# Can't scrape table using XML in Google Sheets

Tags: xml, web-scraping, html-table, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to scrape a table from [CBOE Book Viewer](https://www.cboe.com/us/equities/market_statistics/book/AAPL/?mkt=edgx). I am using Google Sheets to achieve this. My current code is this:

`=importxml("https://www.cboe.com/us/equities/market_statistics/book/GOOGL/?mkt=edgx","/html/body/section/div/div/div[1]/table[2]")`

I do get results, but they are limited to this:
|  Top of Book | Last 10 Trades | Shares Price | Time | Price | Shares |
|:-------------|:---------------|:-------------|:-----|:------|:-------|
|Bid
|Ask

As opposed to:

[image: Webpage results]

...Without context of what is in the table. How can I get the contents of the table in real time?

I've tried using the specific XML paths of each cell without luck and have tried IMPORTDATA function but still couldn't extract data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your URL and HTML data, I thought that when Google Apps Script is used, the values might be able to be retrieved. So, in your situation, how about using a Google Apps Script? The sample script is as follows.

In this URL, it seems that by giving the URL as `referer`, the JSON data can be received.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet, and save the script. When you use this script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE("https://www.cboe.com/us/equities/market_statistics/book/AAPL/?mkt=edgx")` to a cell. By this, the values are retrieved.

```js
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const t = url.match(/www.cboe.com\/us\/equities\/market_statistics\/book\/(.+?)[\/?]/);
  if (t.length != 2) return "Values were not retrieved."
  const endpoint = "https://www.cboe.com/json/edgx/book/" + t[1];
  const params = { headers: { referer: url } };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, params);
  const obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  return obj.data.trades.map(([a, b, c]) => [a, c, b]);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run for the URL of `https://www.cboe.com/us/equities/market_statistics/book/AAPL/?mkt=edgx`, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- From your question, I guessed that you wanted to retrieve the above values. If that was not your expected result, can you provide the detail of your expected values? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: No. Thanks and sorry I didn't see this earlier. I assumed it wouldn't be possible to resolve. That was the correct values I wanted to receive.

Comment: @Nick W Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Nick W About your new question of `Could you help me get data from the left side too where the “bid-ask” is displayed?`, I would like to support you. But, this is difference from your question. So, can you post it as a new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?